# Why webpack gives back the mistake ReferenceError: document is not defined?

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack

The text of the mistake

```
  ERROR in ./static/main.sass
  Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:ReferenceError: document is not defined

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url/resolve-url.js!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./static/main.sass
Module build failed: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.resolveUrl (/home/andrew/Test/node_modules/resolve-url/resolve-url.js:21:25)
```

The webpack.config.js

```
    webpack = require('webpack');
    path = require('path');
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    webpackConfig = {
context: __dirname,
entry: {
    bundle: './static/app.js',
    styles: './static/main.sass'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: './static/build'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
devtool: '#cheap-module-source-map',
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0', 'stage-1']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.sass$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( 'css-loader!resolve-url!sass-loader?sourceMap')
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
        },
        {
            test: /\.woff2?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.svg$|\.png|\.jpe?g|\.gif$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css', {
        allChunks: true
    })
]};
   module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

I thought it may be not having some of the loaders but that's not it.
Besides app.js does not compile in bundle.js too but it doesn't give a mistake. Maybe there is some mistake in entry but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the SCSS file in your `app.js` (either `require` or `import`) and only pass your `app.js` file as entry for Webpack instead of passing the 2 files as entry.